# How to apply a SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.Effect directly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, hlsl, sharpdx

I'm creating an image editor for Windows Phone 8 / Windows 8 using SharpDX api and trying to apply a custom effect (SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.Effect) to a WriteableBitmap.

The effect itself is applied, but the result looks strange. Seems to me that the texture was reduced and inverted.

The code to apply the effect is written below.

```
private void ApplyEffect()
{
    GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice = GraphicsDevice.New();

    RenderTarget2D renderTarget = RenderTarget2D.New( graphicsDevice, _originalBitmap.PixelWidth, _originalBitmap.PixelHeight, PixelFormat.B8G8R8A8.UNorm );

    Texture2D texture = Texture2D.New( graphicsDevice, _originalBitmap.PixelWidth, _originalBitmap.PixelHeight, PixelFormat.B8G8R8A8.UNorm );
    texture.SetData<int>( _originalBitmap.Pixels );

    Effect effect = new Effect( graphicsDevice, SimpleEffectTest.Effects.Invert.EffectBytecode );

    graphicsDevice.SetRenderTargets( renderTarget );

    SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch( graphicsDevice );
    spriteBatch.Begin( SpriteSortMode.Deferred, effect );
    spriteBatch.Draw( texture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White );
    spriteBatch.End();

    renderTarget.GetData<int>( _resultBitmap.Pixels );
}
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong here?

[SimpleEffectTest project](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3B9524A154570D71!853)

Best regards,

Pieter Voloshyn

---- UPDATE ----

After many tests I finally found what I did wrong. I changed the main pixel shader function parameters.

From

```
float4 PS(
    float4 pos  : SV_POSITION,
    float4 posScene : SCENE_POSITION,
    float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0
) : SV_TARGET0
```

To

```
float4 PS(
    float4 color    : COLOR0,
    float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0
) : SV_Target
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take your answer and post it and mark it as an answer! :)