# How to apply barrel distortion (lens correction) with SharpDX?

Tags: c#, shader, sharpdx, distortion

i've made a small application to grap screenshots from any windowed game and send it to the iPhone to creat an virtual reality app, like oculus rift (see https://github.com/gagagu/VR-Streamer-Windows-Server for more info). 
The images will be captured with SharpDX and everything is working fine.
Now i want to implement such like lens correction (barrel distortion) and i'm looking for the fastest way to realize it. I'm looking many internet sites with informations about barrel distortion and i think the fastest way is to use a shader for it, but i'm very new to sharpdx (and no knowledge about shaders) and i don't know how to implement a shader to my code. The most tutorials applys a shader to an object (like a cube) but not to a captured image and so i don't know how to do it.

```
       [STAThread]
    public System.Drawing.Bitmap Capture()
    {
        isInCapture = true;

        try
        {

            // init
            bool captureDone = false;
            bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(captureRect.Width, captureRect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            // the capture needs some time
            for (int i = 0; !captureDone; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    //capture
                    duplicatedOutput.AcquireNextFrame(-1, out duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource);
                    // only for wait
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        using (var screenTexture2D = screenResource.QueryInterface<Texture2D>())
                            device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(screenTexture2D, screenTexture);

                        mapSource = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(screenTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None);
                        mapDest = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, captureRect.Width, captureRect.Height),
                                                              ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

                        sourcePtr = mapSource.DataPointer;
                        destPtr = mapDest.Scan0;

                        // set x position offset to rect.x
                        int rowPitch = mapSource.RowPitch - offsetX;
                        // set pointer to y position
                        sourcePtr = IntPtr.Add(sourcePtr, mapSource.RowPitch * captureRect.Y);

                        for (int y = 0; y < captureRect.Height; y++) // needs to speed up!!
                        {
                            // set pointer to x position
                            sourcePtr = IntPtr.Add(sourcePtr, offsetX);

                            // copy pixel to bmp
                            Utilities.CopyMemory(destPtr, sourcePtr, pWidth);

                            // incement pointert to next line
                            sourcePtr = IntPtr.Add(sourcePtr, rowPitch);
                            destPtr = IntPtr.Add(destPtr, mapDest.Stride);
                        }

                        bitmap.UnlockBits(mapDest);
                        device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(screenTexture, 0);

                        captureDone = true;
                    }

                    screenResource.Dispose();
                    duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();

                }
                catch//(Exception ex)  //                    catch (SharpDXException e)
                {
                    //if (e.ResultCode.Code != SharpDX.DXGI.ResultCode.WaitTimeout.Result.Code)
                    //{
                    //   // throw e;
                    //}

                    return new Bitmap(captureRect.Width, captureRect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                }
            }

        }
        catch 
        {
            return new Bitmap(captureRect.Width, captureRect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        }

        isInCapture = false;
        return bitmap;
    }
```

It would be really great to get a little start assist from someone who willing to help. 
I've found some shaders on inet but it is written for opengl (https://github.com/dghost/glslRiftDistort/tree/master/libovr-0.4.x/glsl110). Can i use the also for directx (sharpdx)?

Thanks forward for any help!

Comment: Basically, you apply a shader to a rectangle which covers the whole screen... in that shader, for each texel, you apply an offset (I can't help you with the calculations right now, but it shouldn't be hard) to the UV of the texture, depending on the XY position.

Answer (score 0):

Now I've never used DirectX myself, but I suppose you'll need to use HLSL instead of GLSL (which should be fairly similar though). The idea is that you'll have to load your "screenshot" into a texture buffer, as an input to your fragment shader (pixel shader). Fragment shaders are deceptively easy to understand, it's just a piece of code (written in GLSL or HLSL) looking very much like a subset of C to which a few math functions has been added (vector and matrices manipulation mostly) executed for every single pixel to be rendered.

The code should be fairly simple, you'll take the current pixel position, apply the barrel distortion transformation to it's coordinates, then look up that coordinate in your screenshot texture. The transformation should look something like that :

```
vec2 uv;

/// Barrel Distortion ///

float d=length(uv);
float z = sqrt(1.0 - d * d);
float r = atan(d, z) / 3.14159;
float phi = atan(uv.y, uv.x);

uv = vec2(r*cos(phi)+.5,r*sin(phi)+.5);
```

[Here's a shadertoy link if you wanna play with it and figure out how it works](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ll2GWV)

I have no idea how HLSL handles texture filtering (which pixel you'll get when using floating point values for coordinates), but I'd put my money on bilinear filtering, which may very well give an unpleasant pixelyness to your output. You'll have to look at [better filtering methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering) once you get the distortion working. Shouldn't be anything too complicated, familiarize yourself with HLSL syntax, find how to load your screenshot into a texture in DirectX and get rolling.

Edit : I said barrel distortion but the code is actually for the fisheye effect. Of course both are pretty much identical, the barrel distortion being only on one axis. I believe what you need is the fisheye effect though, it's what is commonly used for HMDs if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. My main problem ist that i doesn't know how to apply the shader to the loaded bitmap (see my code). I do not have any drawing loop as many games have. I only have a capture loop, grab the image and send it and again. After grabbing i have to apply the shader to the image but how?
Thx all

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, [this](https://advertboy.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/custom-effects-ripple-effect-pixel-shader/) appears to explain in details how to compile and use a shader in your project. If you're not using Visual Studio, you'll have to find out how to compile it yourself (probably using [this](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-d3dcompiler-shaderbytecode-compile-5)) and the article should still help you apply your shader.

Comment: As to how to apply it to an image, [create a graphicsDevice, a renderTarget and use the GetData method once you've drawn it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881946/how-to-apply-a-sharpdx-toolkit-graphics-effect-directly)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply but a was long time very sick.
I've found a shader.fx which include the needed calculation and i want to apply it to the image (above) in the background so the programm should not give an visual output because the image will be send over network.
I really thank you for your help but you replies are making me more confuse as i still be.

Comment: Haha, sorry if I'm not making sense to you. So in the end you did not manage to solve your problem? The link I posted above regarding applying the shader directly to a bitmap didn't work for you?

Comment: I've tested out many ways and spend many time to find a way to apply a barrel distortion to an image in the fastest way possible. I think the main problem is my less knowledge about directx. 
I've tested out to apply a shader to an image in different ways but they all ends in an impasse. I cannot write all because character limit.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118593/how-to-apply-shader-to-an-bitmap-offline-with-sharpdx
https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/issues/607

and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176482/sharpdx-black-screen-on-rendering-my-textured-rectangle