# How to apply shader to an Bitmap offline with SharpDX

Tags: directx, sharpdx

i want to apply a shader to a bitmap (offline processing) with sharpdx. I found a sample on SharpDX homepage to apply an effect to an image with offline processing. Now i want to apply a shader.fx to it but i don't know how to do it.
Can anyone help me out?

Here are the code snipset:

```
// Effect 1 : BitmapSource - take decoded image data and get a BitmapSource from it
    var bitmapSourceEffect = new d2.Effects.BitmapSource(d2dContext);
    bitmapSourceEffect.WicBitmapSource = formatConverter;


    // Effect 2 : GaussianBlur - give the bitmapsource a gaussian blurred effect
    var gaussianBlurEffect = new d2.Effects.GaussianBlur(d2dContext);
    gaussianBlurEffect.SetInput(0, bitmapSourceEffect.Output, true);
    gaussianBlurEffect.StandardDeviation = 5f;

    d2dContext.BeginDraw();
    d2dContext.DrawImage(gaussianBlurEffect);
    d2dContext.EndDraw();
```

Here are the shader.fx

```
vec2 Warp(vec2 Tex)
{
vec2 newPos = Tex;
float c = -81.0/20.0;
float u = Tex.x * 2.0 - 1.0;
float v = Tex.y * 2.0 - 1.0;
newPos.x = c*u/((v*v) + c);
newPos.y = c*v/((u*u) + c);
newPos.x = (newPos.x + 1.0)*0.5;
newPos.y = (newPos.y + 1.0)*0.5;
return newPos;
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
 {
vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;

if (uv.x < 0.5)
{
    uv.x = uv.x * 2.0;
    fragColor = texture2D(iChannel0, Warp(uv));
}
else
{
    uv.x = (uv.x - 0.5) * 2.0;
    fragColor = texture2D(iChannel0, Warp(uv));
}

 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want that on the GPU? I'm not sure if the parallelism will compensate for the overhead of up-/downloading the data and configuring the pipeline. A pure CPU approach might be easier and faster unless you have a very big image. And if it's offline, performance does not really play a role, does it?

Comment: Hi, it needed for a VR App. The image will captured (resolution between HD and Full HD), the shader will create a side by side image and add an barrel distortion to each side. It should look like this image http://pbs.twimg.com/media/B-8RPRqU8AAJQGj.jpg
If you know what the oculus rift is than you know what i mean. If you like to see what my app is than take a look to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuF4zIPjEgM

Thx for helping me

Comment: Then why do you want it offline? Is the image not supposed to be displayed?

Comment: On PC the user will play a game in windowed mode. My App will capture the game window and send it over network to iPhone which is used with vr glasses. Atm the iPhone will display the image on two pictureboxes to simulate a 3D Side-bySide image but lense correction is missing. Between capture and send over network i need to apply the shader to the image. I'm using SharpDX for capturing the image https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct3D11.1/ScreenCapture/Program.cs

Comment: Then use the captured image as a shader resource view. Render a full-screen quad with the shader and send the result (from the back buffer texture) over the network.

Comment: I cannot render in fullscreen because the user i splaying a game while my app is capturing images from it.

Comment: In that context, full-screen means "full viewport". Of course, you would render to an offscreen texture.